# Using a variable as a string within a function (PHP)

Tags: php, syntax

I have a function which is searching through my posts to find a certain category:

```
$thisCatsPosts = $allPosts->findby('category', 'category-one');
```

That works fine and returns exactly what I want when I give it a string like that for it's "needle".

However, I want to use a previously declared variable in place of it. Like thus:

```
$thisCat = $page->title();

$thisCatsPosts = $allPosts->findby('category', $thisCat);
```

However that does not work. I have also tried putting the variable in quotes.

Some specific notes are that I am using the [Kirby](http://getkirby.com) CMS so the functions I'm using are from it's docs. I'm a complete PHP novice. From my understanding though, this is a PHP question and not a Kirby related one.

Many thanks for any help.

EDIT: I have checked that `$thisCat` prints "category-one". I have also checked that the function works when "category-one" is inputted as a string literal.

Comment: What's in `$thisCat`?

Comment: There's no reason why that shouldn't work - have you checked that you're getting the right value in `$thisCat`? If you're after a category, are you sure you should be using a function that looks like it returns a page title?

Comment: `$page->title()`, according to the doc, already returns a string. There should be no reason for your code to fail unless `findby` is failing.

Comment: Yep, I've checked $thisCat using print. The function works perfectly when I put the result of that variable in manually.

Comment: @sanjaypoyzer - can I ask you to add `var_dump($thisCat);` and edit the output into your question?

Comment: @andrewsi Woah, it's really long, and I'm pretty sure most of it isn't relevant. Is there a specific bit you're looking for or do you really want me to paste all of it?

Comment: @sanjaypoyzer - Please add all of it; but that certainly sounds like `$page->title()` isn't just returning a string.

Comment: (if it's anything other than `string(12) "category-one"`, that function doesn't return what you're expecting)

Comment: Well there would be the problem then. I'll add it all in now.

Comment: @sanjaypoyzer - thanks; could you try echoing `$thisCat->value` and see if that outputs `category-one`?

Comment: @andrewsi Yes it does

Comment: ...& adding that to my function has solved the problem! Thanks very much. If you add this as an answer, I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: That's an amazing amount off unnecessary data you're given just for requesting a page title ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like

```
$thisCat = $page->title();
```

Isn't returning a string - it's passing back an object that contains all the details of the page. You should be able to do what you want with:

```
$thisCatsPosts = $allPosts->findby('category', $thisCat->value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try debugging? For instance, use

```
print_r($page->title());
print_r($thisCat);
```

to inspect the values of those variables. Make sure they contain valid data that your findby() method recognizes. If they don't print to the screen you may need to set up some logging calls to print the values to a log, where you can view them.

Comment: Yep, checked the results of those. $thisCat prints "category-one", which as string literal makes the function work but as a variable within it doesn't seem to call it.

Comment: Does it return an error, or just no result? maybe try trim($thisCat) or some other gambit to exclude hidden characters.

Comment: My guess is that the string $thisCat just doesn't match the category field for some reason - maybe an invisible character, character encoding, a typo or something like that

Comment: $thisCat prints the category field just fine though. Exactly the same, even case sensitive, to the test category I've put in as a string.

Comment: obviously if it was exactly the same, it would have exactly the same result :D